# How to pass a variable to a inner class

Tags: java, parameter-passing, inner-classes

I want to use `canvas` inside `mousePressed`. How can I do that?

```
public DragManager(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            canvas.something(); // does not work.
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As many of the guys over here already said you have to make function parameter final.

```
public DragManager(final Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            canvas.something();
        }
    });
}
```

That means that this variable cannot point to any other object. E.g. you cannot do this inside function:

```
canvas = SomeOtherCanvas
```

If you create an object using a local class definition, that object can keep "living" after local variables have been discarded from the stack (after `DragManager` constructor completion). It has to have a copy of the local values. If you make this parameter final (so it's guaranteed that reference inside constructor wouldn't point to some other place) it's really easy to have a copy: just copy a reference. If there was no such rule you (well, not you personally, but Java language) would need to constantly sync those values and that would be much more complex and slow solution.

Answer (score 2):

Make the parameter final:

```
public DragManager(final Canvas canvas)
```

Comment: That means that the canvas variable can't be reassigned to something else in the method, and is a pre-requisite to using the variable inside an anonymous inner class of the method. BTW, I'm sure that the compiler error message says so (and doesn't just say "does not work").

Answer (score 1):

you Cannot refer to non final variable  inside an inner class defined. mark your canvas as final.

```
public void DragManager(final Canvas canvas)
    {

        canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println(canvas);;// does not work.
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public DragManager(final Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            canvas.something(); // does work.
        }
    });
}
```

since you can modify canvas variable, you should define it as final(constant reference).

Answer (score 0):

without using **final** keyword. you can add **Init** method that return **this** and add private variable.
pass canvas by Call Init method.

```
public DragManager(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        Canvas _canvas;
        @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            _canvas.something(); // does not work.
        }
        public MouseAdapter Init(Canvas canvas){
            _canvas = canvas;
            return this;
        }
    }.Init(canvas));
}
```